# In R, Error in order(NULL, integer(0), na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) : argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r

auditing R programming course(coursera)

I've tried reviewing know other solutions and running my code interactively to understand the error, now I'm circling around my own iterations.

> getting traceback error:
>
> Error in order(NULL, integer(0), na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) : 
>      argument 1 is not a vector 
>      6 order(NULL, integer(0), na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) 
>      5 do.call("order", c(z, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) 
>      4 order(complete_data$outcome, complete_data$name) 
>      3 `[.data.frame`(complete_data, order(complete_data$outcome, complete_data$name), 
>          ) at rankhospital.R#60
>      2 complete_data[order(complete_data$outcome, complete_data$name), 
>          ] at rankhospital.R#60
>      1 rankhospital("TX", "heart failure", 4)

My code:

```
rankhospital <- function(state, outcome, num = "best") {

  ## Read outcome data

  data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

  state_col <- data[ , 7] 
  name_col <- data[ , 2]
  attack_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 11]))
  failure_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 17]))
  pneumonia_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 23]))

  best_data <- cbind(state_col, name_col, attack_col, failure_col, pneumonia_col)

  colnames(best_data) <- c("state", "name", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

  best_data <- as.data.frame(best_data)

  ## Check that state and outcome are valid

  list_outcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

  if (!(outcome %in% list_outcomes))
        stop("invalid outcome")

  list_unique_states <- unique(state_col)

  if (!(state %in% list_unique_states))
        stop("invalid state")

  ## Return hospital name in that state with the given rank
  ## 30-day death rate

  state_data <- best_data[best_data$state == state, ]

  #complete_data <- state_data[complete.cases(state_data[,"outcome"]), ]

  complete_data <- state_data[!is.na(state_data[state_data$"outcome", ]), ]

  complete_data <- as.data.frame(complete_data)

  #have data order the outcome by name, 

  ordered_data <- complete_data[order(complete_data$"outcome", complete_data$name), ]

  final_data <- ordered_data

  min_value <- which.min(final_data[, outcome])

  max_value <- which.max(final_data[, outcome])

  if (num == "best") {
        as.character(final_data[min_value, 2])
  } else
        if (num == "worst") {
              as.character(final_data[max_value, 2])
        } else
              {as.character(final_data[num, 2])
        }
  }
}
```

When I run the code interactively, line by line with an example line 60 works just fine.

Comment: Which line is line 60?

Comment: it was the ordered_data <- complete_data[order(complete_data$"outcome", complete_data$name),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the column, which is in the function argument `outcome`, use `state_data[, outcome]`, not `state_data$"outcome"`:

```
download.file("https://github.com/Yang-Zhou/computing-for-data-analysis/blob/master/proj2/outcome-of-care-measures.csv?raw=true", tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))

rankhospital <- function(state, outcome, num = "best") {

  ## Read outcome data

  data <- read.csv(tf, colClasses = "character")


  state_col <- data[ , 7] 
  name_col <- data[ , 2]
  attack_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 11]))
  failure_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 17]))
  pneumonia_col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[ , 23]))

  best_data <- cbind(state_col, name_col, attack_col, failure_col, pneumonia_col)

  colnames(best_data) <- c("state", "name", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

  best_data <- as.data.frame(best_data)

  ## Check that state and outcome are valid

  list_outcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

  if(!(outcome %in% list_outcomes))
        stop("invalid outcome")

  list_unique_states <- unique(state_col)

  if(!(state %in% list_unique_states))
        stop("invalid state")







  ## Return hospital name in that state with the given rank
  ## 30-day death rate

  state_data <- best_data[best_data$state == state, ]


  #complete_data <- state_data[complete.cases(state_data[,"outcome"]), ]




  # complete_data <- state_data[!is.na(state_data[state_data$"outcome", ]), ]
  complete_data <- state_data[!is.na(state_data[, outcome]), ]

  complete_data <- as.data.frame(complete_data)


  #have data order the outcome by name, 

  ordered_data <- complete_data[order(complete_data[, outcome], complete_data$name), ]






  final_data <- ordered_data





  min_value <- which.min(final_data[, outcome])

  max_value <- which.max(final_data[, outcome])


  if(num == "best"){

        as.character(final_data[min_value, 2])

  }else

        if(num == "worst"){

              as.character(final_data[max_value, 2])

        }else

              {as.character(final_data[num, 2])
  }

}

rankhospital("AL", "heart attack")
```